# Laravel - Check if value is equal to any record in collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a collection of records.

```
  $pastSessions = Sessions::where('id', $id)->pluck('event_start_time');
```

This has 12 records.

I'm trying to check if a variable is equal to any of these records, but it's only checking the last one.

```
if($application->appointment == $pastSessions)
```

How do I check is it equal to any of the records.

This is all in my controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains with name of key and value like this.

```
$pastSessions->contains('appointment', $application->appointment)
```